# build error after updating axios on vue3 project using vite

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vite

I have a project that is running vue3 with axios 0.27.2, using vite 4.3.9.

Now I am trying to update axios to 1.6.2 but as soon as I do that, I get an error when trying to do a vite build:

```
[commonjs--resolver] Missing "./lib/helpers/buildURL" specifier in "axios" package
error during build:
Error: Missing "./lib/helpers/buildURL" specifier in "axios" package
```

I am a bit lost, I guess this is a vite problem and not an axios problem, but I have no idea how to fix this. Did anybody else encounter this?

Comment: The migration from version 0.x to 1.x is also discussed in the axios GitHub repository. It might be helpful: https://github.com/axios/axios/discussions/4996 
Here is a link to a repository where they highlight the breaking changes. I suggest reviewing them: https://github.com/bmuenzenmeyer/axios-1.0.0-migration-guide

Comment: In another issue, they might be specifically referring to your problem: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5000. ([answer from @damirbogdanov](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5000#issuecomment-1362395864))

Comment: @rozsazoltan thank you so much, I already went through the migration guide - but the issue 5000 was new to me, so thank you very much for this! In my code I am not directly accessing any /lib/ files so I don't quite understand yet why this is even an issue for me

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @rozsazoltan (thank you so much!) I found [axios/axios #5000](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5000#issuecomment-1362395864) issue. Which lead me to a temporary solution, which is adding this to the vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'axios/lib': resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/axios/lib'),
        },
    },
});
```

But also, I found out that the problem wasn't exactly axios but axios-extensions 3.1.6 which seems to cause the error in concert with the axios update.

What fixed the error as well was updating axios-extensions to 3.1.7 (which is for some reason not defined as current), which fixed the error without having to workaround in my vite.config.js